# Pattern match is Redundant in while updating State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I have a state where it contains different values and I want to use the same function to update different values in the state. But I am unable to do so because of the following error.

Error Received:

warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
Pattern match is redundant
In a case alternative: currentRegister -> ...
|
559 |     currentRegister ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentRegister = nextAddr}
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

````
data St = St
    { cotxt           :: [Cxt] 
    , currentLabel     :: Int
    , currentLogicLabel :: Int
    , currentIfLabel :: Int
    , currentWhileLabel :: Int
    , currentRegister :: Int
    }


getcurrStateValue :: (St -> Int) -> Compile Int
getcurrStateValue  x = do
  current <- gets x  
  let nextAddr = current + 1
  case x of
    currentLabel ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentLabel = nextAddr}
    currentRegister ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentRegister = nextAddr}
    currentLogicLabel ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentLogicLabel = nextAddr}
    currentIfLabel ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentIfLabel = nextAddr}
    currentWhileLabel ->  modify $ \st->st{ currentWhileLabel = nextAddr}

  return current


func1::
..
current <- getcurrStateValue currentRegister
..

func2::
anothercurrent <- getcurrStateValue currentLogicLabel ```
````

Comment: That's not an error, but a warning. The reason this happens is because `currentLabel` in currentLabel -> ...` is a *variable*, so it will match *everything*, as a result, all the other patterns like `currentRgister -> ...`, etc. Will *never* fire.

Comment: You can not pattern match on a function. It might be better to use *lenses* here.

Comment: Also, the fields aren't mutually exclusive possibilities for the value of something of type `St`; *every* value of type `St` has *all* those fields.

Comment: Depending on the wider use case, you might be better off making an enumeration type which corresponds to those constructors, and having your function take that type rather than the function type `St -> Int`. You can pattern match on an enumeration just fine, and be confident you've covered every case. The problem with a function that takes a `St -> Int` argument is that it can take *any* function of that type. That function might always return 1, ignoring its input. It might read all 5 fields and multiply them together - or do weird and arbitrary calculations with them...

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have pointed out, in this `case` expression, you’re trying to *compare* the parameter `x` with the getter functions from the `St` type.

```
case x of
  currentLabel -> modify $ \ st -> st { currentLabel = nextAddr }
  currentRegister ->  modify $ \ st -> st { currentRegister = nextAddr }
  -- …
```

Unfortunately, functions *cannot be compared*; only data constructors and numeric literals (`Num` + `Eq`) can appear in basic patterns. What your code actually does is match `x` against *anything*, and bind it to a *new* local variable `currentLabel`, and then all the subsequent `case` branches (`currentRegister` and so on) are redundant, as the warning tells you.

It’s just as if you had written this, with distinct variable names:

```
case x of
  a -> modify $ \ st -> st { currentLabel = nextAddr }
  b -> modify $ \ st -> st { currentRegister = nextAddr }
  -- …
```

A *simple* solution here is to add a new enumeration type indicating which field you want to modify, and pattern-match on that:

```
data Field
  = CurrentLabel
  | CurrentLogicLabel
  | CurrentIfLabel
  | CurrentWhileLabel
  | CurrentRegister

getCurrStateValue :: Field -> Compile Int
getCurrStateValue field = case field of

  CurrentLabel -> do
    current <- gets currentLabel
    modify $ \ st -> st { currentLabel = current + 1 }
    pure current

  CurrentRegister -> do
    current <- gets currentRegister
    modify $ \ st -> st { currentRegister = current + 1 }
    pure current

  CurrentLogicLabel -> do
    current <- gets currentLogicLabel
    modify $ \ st -> st { currentLogicLabel = current + 1 }
    pure current

  CurrentIfLabel -> do
    current <- gets currentIfLabel
    modify $ \ st -> st { currentIfLabel = current + 1 }
    pure current

  CurrentWhileLabel -> do
    current <- gets currentWhileLabel
    modify $ \ st -> st { currentWhileLabel = current + 1 }
    pure current
```

As you can see, though, this is quite repetitive! A better solution is to pass both a *getter* and a *setter* function (whereas currently you’re only passing the getter):

```
getCurrStateValue
  :: (St -> Int)
  -> (St -> Int -> St)
  -> Compile Int
getCurrStateValue getField setField = do
  current <- gets getField
  modify $ \ st -> setField st $ current + 1
  pure current
```

Of course, now this has moved the repetitiveness to the call site, since you must pass both functions, and they must refer to the same field:

```
current <- getCurrStateValue
  currentRegister
  (\ st x -> st { currentRegister = x })
```

So an improvement would be to package up these invocations into helper functions for each field:

```
getCurrRegister = getCurrStateValue
  currentRegister
  (\ st x -> st { currentRegister = x })

getCurrLogicLabel = getCurrStateValue
  currentLogicLabel
  (\ st x -> st { currentLogicLabel = x })
```

I think this is a good place to stop: the repetition is abstracted away without too much heavy machinery.

However, this can be abstracted further. The combination of a getter and setter for the same field is very useful, and it would be nice to reuse it with other functions besides `getCurrStateValue`.

A getter+setter pair can be packaged up into a *lens* (or more generally an “optic”), which is a *first-class accessor* that can be composed with other lenses. While there are many lens libraries like `lens` (big and complete) and `microlens` (small and simple) containing functions for working with lenses, you don’t actually need any dependencies to *define* a lens; it’s just a function with a type like this:

```
(Functor f) => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Or, slightly simplified:

```
(Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

How this works is beyond the scope of this answer, but what it *means* is an accessor for a field of type `a` within a structure of type `s`. In your case, `a` is always `Int` and `s` is `St`. Here’s a helper function for defining a lens from a getter and setter:

```
lens
  :: Functor f
  => (s -> a)                -- get ‘a’ out of ‘s’
  -> (s -> a -> s)           -- put ‘a’ into ‘s’
  -> (a -> f a) -> s -> f s  -- lens

lens getter setter
  = \ f s -> fmap (setter s) (f (getter s))
```

Using this, you can define lenses for your fields:

```
currentRegisterL, currentLogicLabelL  -- …
  :: (Functor f) => (Int -> f Int) -> St -> f St

currentRegisterL = lens
  currentRegister
  (\ st x -> st { currentRegister = x })

currentLogicLabelL = lens
  currentLogicLabel
  (\ st x -> st { currentLogicLabel = x })

-- …
```

And then use them with functions and types from `lens`, such as `view` to use the getter part and `set` to use the setter.  To take a lens as a function parameter, you need the `RankNTypes` extension, which allows passing polymorphic functions like lenses as arguments to other functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Lens (Lens', set, view)

getCurrStateValue :: Lens' St Int -> Compile Int
getCurrStateValue field = do
  current <- gets $ view field
  modify $ set field $ current + 1
  pure current
```

Most of the time, when using lenses, people don’t write their own by hand, unless they specifically want to avoid a dependency on a lens package. Instead, it’s common to automate this by *deriving* lenses for a data type with Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens.TH (makeLenses)

data St = St
  { _cotxt             :: [Cxt] 
  , _currentLabel      :: Int
  , _currentLogicLabel :: Int
  , _currentIfLabel    :: Int
  , _currentWhileLabel :: Int
  , _currentRegister   :: Int
  }

makeLenses ''St
```

The convention is that the getters and record accessors are prefixed with an underscore, like `_currentLabel`, and the lenses derived from them have no prefix, like `currentLabel`. You can still use the accessor functions directly, but when you need to abstract over field access, you can use `view`, `set`, `over`, and other such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching only works with `data` constructors; it can't check for equality of values. (Patterns like `x:xs`, `[x,y]`, and `(x,y)` are treated constructor matches.) In particular, there is no other general way to handle coproduct types like `data Foo = Bar | Baz`. (Aside from using `Eq`, `Ord`, etc.)

What you probably need here is a [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).